# Adding a new precompile to a local modified Ethereum (geth) node

Tags: go-ethereum

Trying to add a new precompile on the `core/vm/contracts.go` but after re-building the [`go-ethereum`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/) project with `make geth` it doesn't work as it should.

More precisely, I'm following the [Adding a Precompile](https://docs.optimism.io/builders/chain-operators/tutorials/adding-precompiles) tutorial on the Optimism docs but at the end, by running the node with `./build/bin/geth --http --dev`  or `geth --http --dev`, I'm getting all the time `0x` as a result for each `cast call {precompile_address}` call .

What could be the problem?